# The Web API built on windows using Visual studio 2015 ,will work in Linux?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am very new to asp.net core 1.0. I want my services to built on windows platform and host/run on linux or mac. What are the possible ways to do the same ?

Comment: https://blog.tonysneed.com/2015/05/25/develop-and-deploy-asp-net-5-apps-on-linux/

Comment: You can't because it is a WINDOWS/MICROSOFT product family thing.  They call it cross-platform but is restricted to their own platforms, like XBOX etc.